# find examples to prove $ A \cup B $ is not part of the $ V $

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces

For $ A, \: B $ is the subspace of $ V $

Find examples to prove $ A \cup B $ not a subspace of $ V $

I learn about this program should not know how. Desire to help people and give a solution correct!

Comment: Sorry! I learn not good English

Comment: keep practicing  - you have made good start

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Consider $V = \mathbb{R}^2$; there are two very natural subspaces spanned by $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ respectively. Can you use this to find an example of the property you want?

Comment: Find $A\cup B=?$

Comment: @Mrnhan think about the x and y axes in the plane. What happens when you try to add 2 vectors from this set?